# Typeahead Wait issues multiple requests instead of just the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I'm using `bootstrap's typeahead` to get "family's name" from a database. I've read the docs, and I assume everything is ok. However, when I start to search, I 've realized 'search' is too slow and I think it is because the "typeahead" is sending a request for everytime I press a key.

How can I stop sending many requests or try to send the whole string after filling the textbox?

Maybe this information can be helpful

**This is the view:**

[image]

**This is the developer tool's view :**

[image]

**This is the JS:**

*I use a callback to send the request:*

```
var familias = {};
var familiaLabels = [];  

//Callback for searching the string
var buscarFamilia = _.debounce(function( query, process ){

    $.getJSON( '{/literal}{$smarty.const.FAMILIARES_FE_ROOT}{literal}/ws/familia-ajax/', { q: query }, function ( data ) {

        //Clean containers
        familias = {};
        familiaLabels = [];

        //Using some underscore.js for getting data from each item 
        _.each( data, function( item, ix, list ){

            //Fill with the name of each item
            familiaLabels.push( item.nombre );

            //Fill data for the template
            familias[ item.nombre ] = {

              id:item.id,
              nombre:item.nombre,
              padre:item.padre,
              madre:item.madre

            };
        });

        //Return the array
        process( familiaLabels );
    },800);

});
```

This is the config for the "typeahead":

```
$('#alu_familia').typeahead({
    source: function ( query, process ) {

        buscarFamilia ( query, process )
    }
    , updater: function (itemSelected) {

        //This is for getting the id
        $( "#alu_fami_id" ).val( familias[ itemSelected].id );


        return itemSelected;
    }
    ,
    minLength:2,
    matcher: function () { return true; }
    ,highlighter: function(item){
        var p = familias[ item ];
        var itm = ''
                 + "<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>"
                 + "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
                 + "<div class='typeahead_primary'>" + p.nombre + "</div>"
                 + "<div class='typeahead_secondary'><b>Padre: </b>" + p.padre +"</div>"
                 + "<div class='typeahead_secondary'><b>Madre: </b>"+p.madre+ "</div>"
                 + "</div>"
                 + "</div>";
        return itm;
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid making two Ajax requests for the same query by storing any previously retrieved values in a cache object, like this:

```
    var familias = {};
    var familiaLabels = [];  
    var familiasCache = {};
    //Callback for searching the string
    var buscarFamilia = _.debounce(function( query, process ){

    if (typeof familiasCache[query] !== "undefined") {
        return process(familiasCache[query]);
    }

    $.getJSON( '{/literal}{$smarty.const.FAMILIARES_FE_ROOT}{literal}/ws/familia-ajax/', { q: query }, function ( data ) {

        //Clean containers
        familias = {};
        familiaLabels = [];

        //Using some underscore.js for getting data from each item 
        _.each( data, function( item, ix, list ){

            //Fill with the name of each item
            familiaLabels.push( item.nombre );

            //Fill data for the template
            familias[ item.nombre ] = {

              id:item.id,
              nombre:item.nombre,
              padre:item.padre,
              madre:item.madre

            };
        });

        // store result in cache
        familiasCache[query] = familiaLabels;

        //Return the array
        process( familiaLabels );
    },800);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as you said, this modification just stores values ​​previously retrieved. And it's good because it prevents to send any request when a word is repeated.However, What I'd like to know is how can it be sent just one request to the server when the user stop typing.

Comment: your code is using `_.debounce()` so this function is called at max once every 800ms. Because the event here is `keryup` you cant tell when the user has stopped typing unless you are willing to do some complex time calculations which may certainly cost you some responsiveness. So your only choice is to fine tune the debounce time.